# Connecting to localhost from a remote site

Tags: php

I have two sites. One is remote (online) and another localhost (on my developer machine).

The remote site in on dedicated IP address `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` and the localhost machine is public IP `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY`. The remote site is a wesite running online like any other internet site.

Both remote and local machine are running mysql db and PHP.

What I need is to have the remote site (on the internet, IP address `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`) connect to my local machine (with the public IP  `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY`) when some specific webscripts are run by visiters to my website.

How do I establish a connection to my localhost from the remote website using PHP?

Please note that I'am asking for the opposite of normal practice of having a local machine connect to a remote machine.

Comment: Is there a router in the mix with your localhost machine?

Comment: yes there is a router in the mix

Comment: So actually, into which concrete problem did you run? Because if X can connect to Y, Y can to X as well. And configure your router that the port is mapped from the router to your local machine (that one with the non-public IP).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure port forwarding or a DMZ on your router. Port forwarding on port 80 will probably be easiest and more secure (it'll stop web traffic on other ports connecting to your PC which a DMZ would otherwise allow).

The process for setting up port forwarding differs from router-to-router, but it should be relatively easy to find in your router's admin panel. Find the private IP of your PC and, in your router's config, set up so all requests on port 80 to forward to the PC's internal IP.